# How to update mongodb with multiple dynamic keys?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Server receives three dynamic keys: map_id -> section_id -> subsection_id.

User model:

```
{
  _id: userId,
  skills: {
    [map_id]: {
      [section_id]: { 
        [subsection_id]: {
          ...subsectionData
        }
      }
    },
    ...otherMapKeys
  }
}
```

How to update subsection data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution with mongoose [Model.update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update) works correctly:

```
const dynamicLink = `skills.${map_id}.${section_id}.${subsection_id}`;

userModel.update(
    { id: userId },
    { $set: { [dynamicLink]: subsection } },
    { upsert: true }
);
```